# Display problem for the link to view all candidates of the election

Tags: bug, moderator-election

At the bottom of the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election), it looks like this:

> [image: ... eligible and displayedsee all n nominees]
>
> ...eligible and displayed[see all 32 nominees](https://stackoverflow.com/election?all=true)

It looks like it needs some punctuation and spacing.

That text is still there when all the nominees are already displayed, which is slightly misleading but not much of a problem.

Comment: I also think it would be better to show this link at the top, so people can immediately decide to show all. That saves the trouble of finding out which nominees were hidden before after you clicked the link (because while the hiding is done sorted by reputation, the position in the list is not).

Comment: An earlier post about this on meta.stackexchange: [Two minor flaws of the election page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245129/two-minor-flaws-of-the-election-page).