# How Many Moderator Candidates Are There? 32 or 30?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-election

We're in the primary phase of the moderator elections on SO, and I'm a little confused as to how many candidates we have. According to the election page, there are 32, but it only displays 30:

[image]

It also says 32 above the list, however when I counted there were only 30. So which is it?

[image]

I know that during the nomination phase there was an issue with [displaying all the candidates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289853/display-problem-for-the-link-to-view-all-candidates-of-the-election), but the link to display everyone no longer exists.

Comment: I think it means that 32 nominated themselves as candidates, but only 30 out of 32 went to primary. So, there are 30 left.

Comment: They mention there are 32 candidates because, if you read the information box to the side, _candidates can still withdraw during the primary phase_ which would move one of the remaining candidates up. (At least, I assume it would move them up. I don't see why it shouldn't. Either way, take that part with a grain of salt.)

Comment: @Kendra - Then why do we need to see a total that includes people that are no longer in the race? Just list the total number of candidates.

Comment: The total number of candidates is listed: 32. Unless someone withdraws, there are currently 32 candidates. We can only vote on the top 30 by reputation, yes, but there are 32 total.

Comment: i have also same issue there is 30/32 and then 32 candidates similar to above question, but when i counted then one by one i found that they are 29 in total, can anyone tell why they are 29?

Answer (score 17):

There were a total of 32 nominations, out of which, only the first 30, ordered by reputation, continued to the second phase (primaries).

Comment: Why is Amit Joki grayed out, and now only 29 candidates can be voted on? It says he withdrew, so why hasn't one of the other two candidates taken his spot?

Comment: @j08691 Amit withdrew himself. And it would be unfair to insert a nominee after primaries have begun (he'll, almost by definition, get less votes).

Comment: Which brings me back to my original question. Why are we showing 32 candidates in the first place if there are not 32 candidates to vote on?